# Add data to existing excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to add data to an existing excel file, the problem I am facing is that the data is getting imported but the equation and the format is being deleted in original file.

I attached my code below

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

#open the excel file
rb=xlrd.open_workbook('Voltage_T.xlsx')

#make a writable copy of the opened excel file
wb=copy(rb)

#read the first sheet to write to within the writable copy
w_sheet=wb.get_sheet(0)

#write or modify the value at 2nd row first column
w_sheet.write(0,1,'WWW.GOOGLE.COM')

#the last step saving the work book
wb.save('Voltage_WW.xls')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `formatting_info` to true

```
rb=xlrd.open_workbook('Voltage_T.xlsx', formatting_info = True)
```

However xlrd doesn't support xlsx with formatting_info at the moment. So if you really have to use .xlsx you will need another library.

I didn't used it myself so I can't tell you if it's a good library but thanks to a quick search on google **XlsxWriter** seems to answer your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, the formatting_info works as you suggested for xls but the equation in the original file is deleted, the formatting is working now. I will give a try to xlsxwriter

Comment: Glad to help you ! If it answered your question don't forget to accept this as an answer :)